# Possible reasons for "connection abort: recv failed" error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection

We have a application that is using plain and simple JDBC to connect to a database. Now *some* customers who use SQL server complain that every now and then the application crashes. Inspection of a the log file shows error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

In trying to find out the reason of this error I found out some facts that I find rather strange:

- The software might run hours or even days without any problem. Then, suddenly, the error occurs, while doing something that has been done thousand times before. (E.g.: there is a background process, that is polling the database regularly, lets say every 20 seconds, if there is something to do. In the middle of the night when no one is working with the system, this is normally not the case, so the normal background action during the night is only this polling. But, nevertheless, it might happen that it just crashes with this error when doing nothing else than what has been doing for hours.)
- The problem does not occur with systems that use oracle databases. The software is the same, but it does not show the error.
- There is no obvious database maintenance or so going on. Nothing from the side of the database administrators that could be related to the problem.
- I don't find any hints in the event log that could be related to the problem.
- In an attempt to find out if short network problems might be the reason I ran a ping utility (hrping, which also allows to write timestamps). However: As long as the ping is running, the problem is going away. If I stop the ping, then I get back the crashes.
- It does not seem to be related to remote or non remote databases. On one affected system the database is on a different server, on an other affected system it is even on the same server.
- The crashes are very irregularly. If they are often, then they occur several times a day. But it can also run for a month without a problem. To give you an idea of the time pattern I list the crash numbers per day here:

```
Date                           Crash count
------------------------------ -----------
2019-08-06                     1
2019-08-05                     5
2019-08-03                     1
2019-07-31                     1
2019-07-27                     5
2019-07-26                     1
2019-07-24                     1
2019-07-20                     3
2019-07-19                     2
2019-07-18                     2
2019-07-16                     1
2019-07-15                     2
2019-07-14                     1
2019-07-12                     1
2019-07-11                     1
2019-07-10                     1
2019-07-09                     2
2019-07-05                     1
2019-07-01                     1
2019-06-27                     1
2019-06-25                     1
2019-06-24                     1
2019-06-20                     1
2019-06-18                     1
2019-06-17                     5
2019-06-16                     1
2019-06-11                     1
2019-06-10                     1
2019-06-07                     1
2019-06-04                     1
2019-06-03                     2
2019-06-02                     2
```

- We only experience this on very few systems. Other customers use SQL Server databases with the same application and run it without any problems.
- I updated the JDBC driver to the latest version that is compatible (6.4.0), but this did not remove the problem.

Some background information about the software:

we are using Java 7 (1.7.0_80 b15), SQL server version is 2012 (v11.0.5058.0) or 2014 (v12.0.2000.8), respectively.

To find the solution I did a lot of googling, but mostly these errors deal with connection problems on connect - not intermittent in the middle of the work.

By now, I really run out of ideas.... Maybe you have some suggestions what I could check?

Answer (score 0):

> However: As long as the ping is running, the problem is going away. If I stop the ping, then I get back the crashes.

You have remote offices connecting to the SQL Server via a VPN, yes? Sounds like the VPN has an inactivity timeout that's dropping connections on you.

Comment: I don't think so - there are two machines, running in the same network. One machine is hosting the database, one machine is hosting the application. I ran the ping on the application server pinging the database server (which is, as stated, in the same network).